# Recommended drone for 360 HDR sky photography?

Tags: recommendations

Can someone please recommend a drone I could use for amateur 360 HDR sky photography in the USA? I hope recommendation requests like this are on-topic here.

Requirements:

- I will be mounting a Ricoh Theta Z1 360 panorama camera weighing less than 200 grams on top of the drone.
- The camera will be atop a 0.5 meter mast above the drone, so the center of mass will be high (This is so the drone itself will occupy a relatively small region of the panorama image)
- The drone must be able to hold a moderately steady position for about a minute while acquiring the multiple images needed to construct a high dynamic range sky image (True HDR, not just tone mapped).
- The altitude during image acquisition will be roughly 30 meters, to be above nearby trees, power lines, and buildings; so distant sky, clouds, sun, and mountains are the main focus of composition.
- I'm technically skilled, so I can do some assembly and simple electronic work. But I don't want to make a PhD thesis out of this.

Optional:

- The drone should be constructed of narrow struts, so the drone itself occupies as little of the panorama image as possible.
- The drone should be paintable, so I can use color to help edit out the drone image in postprocessing.
- I am a novice pilot; so I also want a recommendation for a cheap durable drone I can use to develop piloting skills before operating my real drone.
- It would be nice to have some way to alternately mount my camera 0.5 meters *below* the drone, for landscape images, but while also protecting my $1000 camera during landing and emergencies. Remember that this camera takes an image in every direction at once, so surrounding the camera with a cage or landing gear is not an option.

Comment: This sounds difficult. If you didn't have to have a perfectly spherical sky, I'd say just use an Air 2S. Having a mass half a meter above the drone is going to adversely affect the stability.

Comment: @Nate Graham Maybe I could put a counterweight below to keep the center of mass in the center of the drone. I could mount my camera on top, and use the on-board camera, pointed down, for optical feedback stabilization. Please consider posting an answer describing the positive qualities of the Air 2S.

Comment: What is the budget of this drone?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guy hanging a 360 camera from a Mavic air 2. He had some issues getting the drone to land or automatically landing during flight but his rig might work for your needs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo4yg8lsHQw

Comment: What are some aspects of the Mavic air 2 that make it a good option? Considering that the OP asks for a cheap and durable drone, do the benefits of the Air 2 outweigh its relatively high price?

Comment: A used DJI Phantom 3 pro would be a good fit since these are no longer made and relatively cheap.  This model includes return to home and some optical avoidance.  The drone has a good surface area for camera attachment and landing gear to attach counterweights if needed.